# How to redirect to my application from Skype app in ios

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am new for ios app and in my project i have given "Skype" usage facility for users and according to my code i can redirected to Skype application and everything is Ok

Here my main requirement is when i make audio or video call from my app there is one button available in Skype application that is "Call ended" button see below that image i posted

when i clicked that button (i.e when ended the call) i want to directly redirect to my app

### my code:-

```
BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]]; 

if(installed) {

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:%@?call", userNameString]]]; 

}
 else {

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]]; 
}
```

But here when i click that below call ended button i want to directly redirected to my Ios app please help me some one

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this. When you load the Skype application to make a call it would have to redirect to your app using another URL scheme (which obviously Skype probably won't do).

Essentially when you load the Skype app, your app goes into the background. The only way to bring your app back to the foreground (without a URL scheme to load it again) is for the user to load it themselves.

Comment: i think that's not correct process because everytime when user make call then app automatically goes to background the again user need to load the app it's really hesitate users ,and is there any another better process available please let me about that with your help

Comment: It is annoying for the user but AFAIK there really is no way to do this.

Comment: only this is not possible in ios app? or not possible in android also

Comment: I couldn't answer that I'm afraid.